# How to decode mixed string with unicode symbols?

Tags: unicode, utf-8, abap, x509

Yesterday I was confused by output of FM `SSFC_PARSE_CERTIFICATE`. It serves for decoding fields of [X.509 certificate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X.509) into readable format.

Everything is OK for latin symbols, but cyrillic letters are turned into something like `\u041F\u0440\u0438\u0432\u0435\u0442`.

Besides, if original text contains mixed symbols, i.e. latin, non-latin, spaces and digits, the task becomes even more comlex: `Hello! \u041F\u0440\u0438\u0432\u0435\u0442 1234`.

I [wrote some code myself](https://gist.github.com/yaruson/1cc0046d9f6cd043c2b2) to scan string character by character and decode single entities using `CL_ABAP_CONV_IN_CE=>UCCP` and it seems to work well, but I'd like to know if there is a standard way to acheive same result?

Comment: Is your system an unicode system? Is your program in unicode mode?

Comment: @Philipp yes, system is unicode and program is unicode as well

Comment: @Yaruson, attach sample of `SSFC_PARSE_CERTIFICATE` in order we can analyze it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it's seams like in your input xstring all non-latin charcodes have been escaped instead of being encoded in UTF8. So if you not satisfied with your DIY solution, you should work upstream of the call to FM SSFC_PARSE_CERTIFICATE

Comment: Unfortunately SSFC_PARSE_CERTIFICATE internally calls some system function and I was unable to dig deeper into it. For the moment DIY solution works well.